# Get HTML page by URL

Tags: node.js

Here is my code:

```
 utilitesRouter.route('/url')
    .post(function(request, response) {
        console.log(request.body.uri);
        var urlOpts = { host: request.body.uri, path: '/', port: '80', method: 'GET' };
        var re = /(<\s*title[^>]*>(.+?)<\s*\/\s*title)>/gi;
        http.get(urlOpts, function (response) {
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                var str=chunk.toString();
                console.log(str);
                var match = re.exec(str);
                if (match && match[2]) {
                    console.log(match[2]);
                }
            });    
        });

        response.json({ url: request.body.uri });    
    });
```

If I use POST request with this JSON `{"uri":"google.ru" }` I get:

```
302 Moved
google.ru
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.ru/index.html">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

If I use POST requiet with JSON `{"uri":"http://google.ru" }` I get the error message:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://google.ru
    at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
```

I can open http://google.ru in my browser.

How can I get the HTML using node.js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to [request](https://github.com/request/request) to do that. It just pretty easy.

```
var request = require("request");

router.get('/proxy', function(req, res, next){
  request.get( req.body.uri, function(error, response, body){
    if( error )
      return next(error);

    res.send(body);
  });
});
```

**request** also support streaming and other cool features too.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because in your `urlOpts` the attribute `host` has to be a domain name, like `google.ru` or `www.google.ru`. As you are putting a URL into it, it can't be resolved to an IP via DNS, that's why you get the error `at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)`.

If you want to use `http.get()` like the way you do, you would always have to extract the domain part out of your passed `uri`, i.e. getting `google.ru` out of `http://google.ru` to use it as `host`.

Comment: It doesn't explain why I can get the page using `{"uri":"google.ru" }` and how  can I get it

Comment: @demas `google.ru` is working because it is a domain name and can be resolved via dns. Open up a normal console / terminal and do `ping google.ru`, then you will be able to see the IP. If you do `ping http://google.ru` you will get an error - the same error you just posted in your question. `http.get()` expects a host / domain name in its `host` paremeter, not a URL.

Comment: No, I get `302 Moved` for any page using `{"uri":"google.ru" }` - look at my question.